# Set a value into multiple columns

Tags: javascript, sorting, google-apps-script

I want to set a value from the value that i get from the sheet1 and pass it into sheet2 and this is my code

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ss1 = ss.getSheetByName('sheet1');
var ss2 = ss.getSheetByName('sheet2');
nextrow = ToSheet.getLastRow();
nextcolum = ToSheet.getLastColumn();

function myfuction() {
  var data1 = ss1.getRange(1,1).getValue()
  var data2 = ss1.getRange(2,1).getValue()
  var data3 = ss1.getRange(3,1).getValue()

  var data4 = ss1.getRange(4,1).getValue()
  var data5 = ss1.getRange(5,1).getValue()
  var data6 = ss1.getRange(6,1).getValue()

  var myarray1 = [[data1] , [data2], [data3]];
  var myarray2 = [[data4] , [data5], [data6]];
  var myarray3 = [data....data];
  var myarray4 = [data...data];
  var i = 0;
  while(i < 3) {
    if (myarray1[i].length != 0) { //Check if the one of value of array have a value
      ss2.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns).setValues(myarray1)
      //assume that the value of getrange(nextrow+1, 1, 1, 3)
    } 
    if(myarray2[i].toString().length != 0 ) { //Check if the one of value of array have a value
      ss2.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns).setValues(myarray2)
      //assume that the value of getrange is nextrow+1, 1, 1, 3
    }
    if() {//a two if for myarray3 and myarray4 also
    }
    i++;
  }
}
```

Inside of while loop i use if to know if one of the value inside of the array(myarray1, myarray2) have a value if the result is != 0 (have a value on it) then the ss2.getRange will execute if not nothing will happen,

(I Update/Edit the Post)

Answer (score 0):

Are data1, data2 and data3 single values or arrays?

If they are single values, which I assume given you give a range height of 1 you need to `setValues([[data1, data2, data3]]);`.

The way you are doing it now could write the data when using `getRange(nextRow+1,mycolumn,3,1);`, i.e. a columnvector.

Google Spreadsheets sets and gets values as arrays of rowvectors, i.e. every element of the array is a row and an element of values that become the column value in that row.

Comment: the data1, data2, data3 are from user input text and also the data1, data2, data3 are optional if the user want to add some text on it, my script should   insert the value into one row and multi column  i mean A1:C1,

Comment: Ok Thanks, My array is still like this var mydata = [[data1] , [data2] ,[data3]]; how can i insert it into multiple column? in ToSheet.getRange(nextRow+1,mycolumn,1,3).setValues(mydata); i still got the error msg. of Incorrect range height, was 3 but should be 1

Comment: You didn't change what's causing the error. The format you are using is `[[d1],[d2],[d3]]` for the row but it is a column vector, the data needs to be in the format `[[d1,d2,d3]]` if you want to paste a row.

Comment: A Ok thanks, i change try to run it and use myarray1.toString().length with out entering an value on it, it also count the comma (,) I'm assuming the value that i get is 0 or null, cause I din't enter some text on it, any idea on how can i check if the user enter an text on it?